# Add a suffix to file basenames in a directory

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I am trying to create a batch file to add the suffix `_Reuploads` to the basenames of all CZI files in a directory named `Reuploads`.

The file names in `Reuploads` follow the basename format `AB123456_pX_s0_m0`, (sometimes they follow the format `AB123456_pX_s0_m0_R1`, not sure if this matters?).

I found this code, and edited it, but it does not seem to work.

```batch-file
@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "C:\Reupload" /s /b /a-d ^| findstr /v "_Reupload\.[^.]*$"') do ( ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni_Reupload%%~xi" )
```

Comment: "it does not seem to work" is most certainly not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: Almost like how your comment is not helpful in the slightest.

Comment: You are expected to tell us what is actually happening, and provide all output/error/debugging information. This is a technical help site, not a guessing game.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that it cannot possibly work because your code does not attempt the task you laid out. The reason for that is glaringly obvious to me; it will never locate a directory named `Reuploads` and suffix `_Reuploads` if you are telling it to look for a directory named `Reupload` and suffix `_Reupload`. Now, I'm sure you're going to tell us that it doesn't make any difference if you correct those basic things, but can you see how not making an effort to properly detail and explain things is not how to get a focused response to a specific programming issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


for /r C:\ %%d in (.) do (
    if /i "%%~nxd"=="Reuploads" (
        echo Found folder: %%d
        pushd %%d
        for %%f in (*.czi) do (
            set "filename=%%f"
            if not "!filename!"=="!filename:_Reuploads=!" (
                echo File already has suffix: %%f
            ) else (
                ren "%%f" "!filename!_Reuploads.czi"
                echo Renamed: %%f
            )
        )
        popd
    )
)

echo.
echo Renaming complete.
pause
```

But it may be slow because it looks in all the computer for the "reuplods" folder.

Comment: Thank you- I tried this and it work! What if I know the specific path of the "Reuploads" folder? Like, say each computer has a Reuploads folder on the desktop. Would specifying more where the folder is increase the speed?

Comment: you are welcome, if you know the path then you can just do 
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "reuploadsPath=path\to\Reuploads"
for %%f in ("%reuploadsPath%\*.czi") do (
    set "filename=%%~nxf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!_Reuploads.czi"
    echo Renamed: %%f
)
echo.
echo Renaming complete.
pause

please accept the answer if it is ok

Comment: "a Reuploads folder on the desktop" - that would be `"%userprofile%\Desktop\Reuploads"